# Using upper-bounds for immutable collections

Tags: scala, types, liskov-substitution-principle

I am trying to create a method which could take a type parameter of any descendant of `immutable.Seq`. This is what I got so far:

```scala
def writeSomeData[Holder[_] <: Seq[String]](path: String, holder: Holder[String]): Unit = {
// irrelevant implementation
  }
```

However when I call the above method with an `immutable.List`:

```scala
writeSomeData(tmp, List(res1, res2, res3, res4, res5))
```

it breaks with the following error:

```sh
[error] /home/v.gorcinschi/repos/...: inferred type arguments [List] do not conform to method writeSomeData's type parameter bounds [Holder[_] <: Seq[String]]
[error]       writeSomeData(tmp, List(res1, res2, res3, res4, res5))
[error]       ^
[error] /home/v.gorcinschi/repos/...: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[String]
[error]  required: Holder[String]
[error]       writeSomeData(tmp, List(res1, res2, res3, res4, res5))
```

Why is this happening and how must I correct it? `List` is a descendant of a Seq isn't it? [image]

Comment: Indeed you're right! Do you want to post your comment as answer?

Comment: You declared `Holder` as a higher-order type, but set a bound of non higher order type, so it will never match. Luis' solution is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Holder[_] <: Seq[String]` doesn't mean what you think it does. I am actually not sure what does it mean, probably something like: `trait Holder[A] extends Seq[String]` which as you can see is very different from how **List** would look like.

You actually want to express that `Holder[String]` should be a subtype of `Seq[String]` many people think the right syntax for that is `Holder[_] <: Seq[_]` However, that is also incorrect; that just means that **Holder** must extend **Seq** but doesn't guarantee that `Holder[String] <: Seq[String]`
Thankfully, **Scala** does provides syntax to represent that: `Holder[x] <: Seq[x]` that `x` is not another type parameter, is just a way to say that `Holder[x]` is a subtype of `Seq[x]` for any type `x`

Sometimes, you it is also easier to use a generalized type constraint like:

```scala
def foo[Holder[_]](holder: Holder[String])(implicit ev: Holder[String] <:< Seq[String]): Unit
```

To represent that exact same relationship.

---

Nevertheless, that is only useful if you reference **Holder** in the return type, if you only want to consume any **Seq** then you can just do:

```scala
def foo(holder: Seq[String]): Unit
```

Thanks to Liskov, you can pass any subtype of `Seq[String]` there.

Answer (score 1):

The type constraint

```
Holder[_] <: Seq[String]
```

means method takes any type constructor `Holder` such that `Holder[X]` is a subtype of `Seq[String]` for arbitrary `X`. By arbitrary we mean `X >: Nothing <: Any`.

Now when you pass `List("")` as argument then Scala will try to unify

```
?Holder := List
```

such that `Holder[X] <: Seq[String]` for arbitrary `X`. However `List[X]` is not a subtype of `Seq[String]` for arbitrary `X`, for example take `X := Int`. Hence it does not type check.

As a workaround we can do

```
Holder[x <: String] <: Seq[x]
```

This effectively achieves the same thing but this time it works because now

`Holder[x] <: Seq[x]`

does hold true for arbitrary `x` because both `List` and `Seq` are similarly defined

```
trait Seq[+A]
trait List[+A]
```

and it is true that `[X] =>> List[X]` <: `[X] =>> Seq[X]` for arbitrary `x`.

Plus compiler has extra information `x <: String` from `Holder[x <: String]` to check the element type of the argument.

Given

```
Holder[_] <: Seq[String]
```

You could make it work by helping out the compiler with explicitly passing appropriate type lambda something like so

```
writeSomeData[[X] =>> List[String]](???, List(""))
```

but Scala does not infer such type lambdas automatically I think because of in general type constructor unification being [undecidable](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/better-type-inference-for-scala-send-us-your-problematic-cases/2410/140?u=mario-galic).

Comment: If you write `Holder[x <: String] <: Seq[x]`, doesn't it mean Holder is upper bounded by Seq type constructor instead of a full type of Seq[String]? That is not the same as `Holder[x <: String] <: Seq[String]`. If you do that, it still won't match

Comment: @texasbruce No the upper bound `<: Seq[x]` is not a type constructor.

Comment: I am saying that if your theory is right and we put a type constraint on the type parameter of Holder, it should work, because `List[String]` would then `<:< Holder[x]` because `x <: String`, but it doesn't

Comment: @texasbruce Not sure I understand, it seems to work here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Pe2sVGE1TfKgWyvcW2Ne7A

Comment: That's because instead of `Seq[String]` you have `Seq[x]`. According to your theory, this should work `def f[Holder[_ <: String] <: Seq[String]](holder: Holder[String])` but it does not

Comment: @texasbruce No that constraint does not have the same effect as `Holder[x <: String] <: Seq[x]`.  There is nothing wrong conceptually with `Holder[_ <: String] <: Seq[String]` it is just a fundamental limitation to check such constraints in all cases.

Comment: It cannot check all cases but it should match the case in OP's code because the type parameter being matched is just String. It does not work even in OP's case.

Comment: @texasbruce Please see edited answer. Note how inference algorithm needed help.

Comment: You mentioned `Holder[x]` didn't work because x here is `x <: Any`, and it should be `x <: String`. In your new update,  you are passing a type lambda that takes anything and generate `List[String]` so no matter what x you are passing you get a `List[String]`. That is not the same as your previous explanation.